# Final Topology Generated by Inclusion Map

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, continuity, limits-colimits

Let $Y\subset X$  (strict inclusion) and let $\tau^Y$ be a topology on $Y$.  Then, we may endow $X$ with the final topology induced by the inclusion (map) $i:Y\rightarrow X$.

- **Question:**  Is there an intuition behind this topology?  Does it agree with the subspace topology when restricting back to $Y$?
- **A Concrete Example:**
  To help with ideas.  Say $Y=C_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and $X=C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and $Y$ is equipped with the topology of uniform convergence.  What would the final topology on $X$ be?  It can't be the compact-convergence topology since otherwise $\overline{Y}=X$ which is clearly not the case....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, very explicitly, a subset $U\subseteq X$ is open in the final topology iff $U\cap Y$ is in $\tau^Y$.  In particular, this means every subset of $X\setminus Y$ is open, and a subset of $Y$ is open iff it is in $\tau^Y$.  So, $X$ just has the topology of the disjoint union $(X\setminus Y)\sqcup Y$ where $X\setminus Y$ has the discrete topology and $Y$ has the topology $\tau^Y$.  (So yes, the subspace topology on $Y$ is $\tau^Y$.)

Comment: Right, so in lamens terms, its the finest topology on $X$ which allows $Y$ to be a subset of $X$?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to describe it (if by "subset" you mean "subspace").

Comment: Right (just to be sure) so if $Y\subseteq X$ and $X$ is equipped with a topology $\tilde{\tau}$ which is coarser then the subspace topology when restricted to $Y$... Then the final topology generated by $\{i,1_X\}$ is equal to $Y \sqcup (X\backslash Y)$ (where $Y$ has its (finer) topology and $X\backslash Y$ has its subspace topology?)

Comment: No.  I'm not sure what you mean by "coarser then the subspace topology when restricted to $Y$", but the final topology will definitely be coarser than $\tilde{\tau}$, since it needs to make $1_X$ continuous.  If you mean that the subspace topology of $\tilde{\tau}$ on $Y$ is coarser than $\tau^Y$, then the final topology is just $\tilde{\tau}$.  If you mean the other way around, then there isn't any particularly simple description of the final topology (it consists of those elements of $\tilde{\tau}$ whose intersection with $Y$ is in $\tau^Y$).

Comment: Oh I meant the final topology for $\{i,1_X|_{X-Y}=1_{X-Y}\}$ excuse my typo, please.

Comment: Then that's correct.

Comment: I gave is some though and I meant to say that $\tau^Y$ is *finer* than the subspace topology induced by restriction of $X$ ($\tilde{\tau}$ is the topology on $X$).  It seems like this space shouldn't be disconnected... My confusion arises from this example I came up with.... if $Y$ is dense in $X$ then it should still be dense for the final topology generated by $\{i,1_{X-Y}\}$ no?

Sorry for the many questions, but I think I confused myself...